# Elevation property not working in api >= 27

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-elevation

I am setting the elevation property on my AppBarLayout & it works from api 21 to 26 but the shadow isn't shown on device, emulator running on api >= 27.

Has there been any change with AppBarLayout or elevation property?

here's how I am using the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: try adding a bottom margin, it might be that there just isnt any space to show the shadow.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund tried, not working.. seems like toolbar shadows aren't shown on api >= 27.

Comment: Try setting elevation on Toolbar instead of AppBarLayout (use app:elevation)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the app:elevation attribute with namespace as app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Have you tried `StateListAnimator`**.

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
            stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(appBarLayout, "elevation", 0.1f));
            appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
}`

**OR**

- **Try Setting Background**

`android:background="@android:color/white"
 android:elevation="10dp"`

Hope it works !

Comment: Yes, no effect even after using `app` namespace.

Comment: Ok let me check something else

Comment: android:outlineProvider="bounds" try this

Comment: tried setting background  ?? android:background="@android:color/white"
android:elevation="10dp"

Comment: If I set AppBar and Toolbar's background to white, I see the Shadow.. but I'm changing the Toolbar's background color programmatically, so unable to create the shadow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191708/discussion-between-abhinandan-sharma-and-darshan).

Answer (score 0):

remove `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>` if exists in `AndroidManifest.xml`